# Docker pull then start for running container - what is the expected behavior?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

Let's say I have a running Docker container **X** that is based on image *foo*.

If I pull a new version of *foo*, then stop and delete **X**, and then `docker run foo` - will it start the new version of the image?

Said differently - do I need to stop **X** before I can pull the new version of *foo* and then start it?

<sub>Context: Docker-EE on Windows Server 2016</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the new version of the image without stopping the original.  Docker does not see them as the same image as their layer hashes will differ.